# Functions not running concurrently in C

Tags: c, concurrency

I'm trying to make two function run concurrently in C using fork(), for some reason c1 seems to be executing twice, and c2 never gets executed. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void c1();
    void c2(char *argv[]);
    int wait_rv;        /* return value from wait() */
    int child_status;
    int pid1,pid2,pid3,parentPID;

    parentPID = getpid();

    if((pid1 = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork  child1 \n");
    }else{
        c1();
        exit(17);
    }

    if((pid2 = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork  child 2\n");
    }else{
        c2(argv);
        exit(17);
    }

    int i;
    if( argc >= 2 )
    {
        printf("The arguments supplied are:\n");
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\t", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please provide the file path as command line argument\n");
    }

    c2(argv);

}

void c1()
{
    int counter = 0;
    float grades[10];
    float result = 0;
    printf("child %d here. Will calculate average marks.\n", getpid());
    printf("Please enter 10 marks: \n");

    do{
        printf("(%d)",counter+1);
        scanf("%f",&grades[counter]);
        counter++;
    }while(counter < 10);

    for(counter;counter>=0;counter--){
        result = result + grades[counter];
    }

    printf("Average: %f",result/10);
}

void c2(char *argv[] ){
    FILE *fptr;
    char ch;
    int wrd=1,charctr=1;
    printf("child %d here. Will execute wc\n", getpid());

    fptr=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf(" File does not exist or can not be opened.");
        perror(fptr);
    }
    else
    {
        ch=fgetc(fptr);
        while(ch!=EOF)
        {
            if(ch==' '||ch=='\n')
            {
                wrd++;
            }
            else
            {
                charctr++;
            }
            ch=fgetc(fptr);
        }
        printf("\n The number of words in the  file %s are : %d\n",argv[1],wrd-2);
    }
    fclose(fptr);

}
```

This is my output:

```
child 27931 here. Will calculate average marks.
Please enter 10 marks:
(1)child 27932 here. Will calculate average marks.
Please enter 10 marks:
(1)1
(2)2
(3)3
(4)4
(5)5
(6)6
(7)7
(8)8
(9)9
(10)10
(2)1
Average: 4.600000-bash-4.1$
```

for some reason it gets all messed up and tries to get one extra mark at the end.

Comment: Why do you think `c2()` will get executed? Both the parent and child from the first `fork()` call `c1()` and then exit.

Comment: Did you intend to call `c1()`  and then exit in both the parent and child processes? That's what you're doing. See the [manual page for `fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). It explains the return value.

Comment: Yes I just realised that. What I wanted to do is to run both c1 and c2 at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
int pid = fork();
// Check if forking failed
if(pid == -1) exit(1);
// If we are in child, run c1
else if(pid == 0) {
    // Code here will ONLY be run by child
    c1(argv);
}
// If we are in parent, run c0
else {
    // Code here will ONLY be run by parent
    c0();
}
// Anything that comes after here will be run by BOTH processes
// unless they exit first
```

What you need to understand here is that right after the call to fork (unless it failed) you have two processes running. For each of them, you can find out which it is by inspecting the value of `pid`.